# Manually add @Required to the primary field to maintain the same behavior as 0.88.3 (upgrade to 0.89.0)

Tags: android, realm

I just updated realm from 0.88.3 to 0.89.0. In the [changelog](https://realm.io/news/realm-java-0.89.0/) it says

*PrimaryKey fields are no longer automatically marked as @Required. They can now be null if the type of the field can usually be null.
This change will throw a RealmMigrationNeededException. Either manually add @Required to the primary field to maintain the same behavior as 0.88.3 and below, or change the nullability in a migration step.*

What I tried:

1.
Add @Required to the object but it throws "Error:(542, 114) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to long"

```
public class Migration{
   .
   .
   . 
   schema.get("Retailer")
      .setRequired("id", true);
   .
   .
}

@RealmClass
public class Retailer extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey @Required
    private String id;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

How to do it correct?

Comment: It was a known bug which has been fixed by https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2653 . You can use `0.89.1` which has the fix. Really sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you, it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to beeender, I updated to the newer version 0.89.1 and it is working now.

Just add @Required to you existing Primary key and no migration is needed.

```
@RealmClass
public class Retailer extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey @Required
    private String id;
}
```

If you add a new RealmObject to your project you have to write the following migration:

```
schema.create("Retailer")
    .addField("id", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
```